# Open csv file in utf-8 with Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm losing my mind here. I've read and tried so much things that I'm totally lost.
I don't usually use Python, and I'm trying to update a code. 
Before, csv files did not contains any specials characters (like "é"...) and now it does.
The actual code returns the exception UnicodeEncodeError :

```
try:
        self.FichierE = codecs.open(self.CheminFichierE,"r", "utf-8")
        self.ReaderFichierE = csv.reader(self.FichierE, delimiter=';')
    except IOError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(u"Fichier E n'a pas été trouvé")
        return

try:
        DataFichierE = [ligne for ligne in self.ReaderFichierE]
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible")
        return
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible (ASCII)")
        return
```

I've tried so many things, I'll just put the last thing I did (and that I thought it should work) :

```
try:
        DataFichierE = []
        for utf8_row in self.ReaderFichierE:
            unicode_row = [x.decode('utf8') for x in utf8_row]
            DataFichierE.append(unicode_row)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible")
        return
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible (ASCII)")
        return
```

Any help will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.12.0).

```
import pandas
myfile = open('myfile.csv')
data = pandas.read_csv(myfile, encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', delimiter=';')
print(data.values)
```

or [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/)

```
import unicodecsv
myfile = open('myfile.csv')
data = unicodecsv.reader(myfile, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=';')
for row in data:                                                 
    print row
```

You may be able to install them using pip:

pip install pandas

pip install unicodecsv

Depending on your needs you may also try simple string operations:

```
data = [line.strip().split(';') for i, line in enumerate(open('./foo.csv').readlines()) if i != 0]
```

**Update**
You can also try replacing unicode characters with ASCII equivalents:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import codecs
import unicodedata

...

    try:
        self.FichierE =  StringIO(
            unicodedata.normalize(
                'NFKD', codecs.open(self.CheminFichierE, "r", "utf-8").read()
            ).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        self.ReaderFichierE = csv.reader(self.FichierE, delimiter=';')

    except IOError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(u"Fichier E n'a pas été trouvé")
        return

    try:
        DataFichierE = [ligne for ligne in self.ReaderFichierE]
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible")
        return
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        self.TextCtrl.AppendText(self.NomFichierE+ u" n'est pas lisible (ASCII)")
        return
```